# Django (REST Framework) Returns Empty List Every Other Call

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

I have a simple function that generates a random sample list of items from the outer dictionary.

```
def get_random_product_feed_for(mid, n=DEFAULT_AMOUNT_ITEMS_RETURNED):

    assert mid is not None, 'Merchant ID cannot be null while retrieving products feed'
    n = min(n, MAX_FEED_ITEMS_RETURNED)

    if mid in ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS: # check if merchant is present in the outer dict

        feeds = ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS[mid] # retrieve merchant's items

        # Sample list
        if len(feeds) >= n:
            random_feeds = random.sample(feeds, n)
        else:
            random_feeds = feeds


        return random_feeds

    return []
```

Where `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS = defaultdict(list)`.

However, when I use this function in REST Framework API call, it returns empty list half the time; every other call. I don't think, however, the problem is in views or serializers.

Nevertheless, the setup is a little bit more complex than this. `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` is fetched asynchronously, because it is processed from large files that need to be downloaded.

```
threads = [] # to keep only one active thread for the process
def fetch_products_feed():

    for thr in threads:
        if not thr.is_alive():
            threads.remove(thr)

    if len(threads) > 0:
        logging.warning(
            'Attempted to create multiple threads for product feeds fetching process. '
            'Wait until it is done!'
        )
        return

    thread = threading.Thread(target=fetch_products_feed_sync, name='Fetch-Products-Thread')
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

So far I can only assume that `fetch_products_feed_sync` is doing its job properly as well (in sake of not overcomplicating the question). It just reads the items and adds them to `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS`.

This whole setup actually works locally, but I host the server on AWS. So the problem appears only there. Locally I get the result every call.

I can only suggest that threading messes everything up. Am I right? I hoped that since the main thread only reads `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` and not changes it, it should be fine.

Maybe every call, the application changes the thread or something. So, at first, `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` has values in it, but at the next step (call) `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` has no values, because the application is in another thread?

How would you advice me to debug it, considering everyone has tough time debugging things on AWS?

I see that, for example, if `mid` is passed incorrectly, then it returns empty list, but it seems not to be a problem (I will try to debug it and give an update on that later).

**Updates:**

It was discovered that the problem is in `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` being empty in the scope of `get_random_product_feed_for` every other call. I tried to debug the name of the thread that is active inside `get_random_product_feed_for`. Seems like both successful (`ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` having items) and unsuccessful (`ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` having no items) calls are coming from MainThread. So, why MainThread at one point has access to data, at the next moment (function call) it doesn't, the moment afterward it has it again, etc?

Comment: As a debug step, you could add another `assert` that checks if `len(ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS) > 0`.

Comment: @C14L ok. So, the server now returns 500 every other call, which I assume due to the assert being triggered. Thus, I can deduce that the problem is not in `mid` being incorrect, but `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` being empty every other call. Any thoughts for the reason? The only reason I can think of is my multithreading implementation, but how to fix it or what is the core problem?

Comment: Where does `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` come from? Maybe the async downloading hasn't finished yet? Could be that is downloads faster locally, so it works locally?

Comment: @C14L well, I have the production and test server. Production server has been fetching elements since yesterday, so it should be done by now. The test server is currently fetching elements, since I triggered it just half an hour ago. `ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` is composed from CSV files from multiple URLs using pandas. I believe it takes around an hour to fetch all elements both locally and on AWS. Memory utilisation shouldn't be an issue, since I keep only a small part of data in memory. But I should be able to access data that was modified in different thread while thread is still running?

Comment: @C14L Additional information: I debugged the name of the thread that is calling the function. Seems like both successful (`ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` having items) and unsuccessful (`ADVERTISERS_PRODUCT_FEEDS` having no items) calls are coming from `MainThread`. So, why `MainThread` at one point has access to data, at the next moment (function call) it doesn't, the moment afterward it has it again, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem appears to be in multiple processes that AWS creates for WSGI.**

I discovered that if you tweak `NumProcesses` in AWS's configuration, then the rate of failed results will increase accordingly. So, if I have `NumProcesses=3`, then the application will return empty set 2/3. Which means that only one of three processes has fetched the wanted data.

As far as I understood, there is no solution to share memory among the processes. The only solution that can be done is to persist the data (e.g., in database).